# Convert a double value to Packed decimal COBOL format PIC S9(5)V9(4) COMP-3/Packed decimal COBOL format PIC S9(3)V9(4) COMP-3 format in JAVA

Tags: java, double, cobol, packed-decimal

I am trying to convert a double value to Packed decimal COBOL format PIC S9(5)V9(4) COMP-3/Packed decimal COBOL format PIC S9(3)V9(4) COMP-3 format in JAVA, see below example :

Double Value : 00000.6775
Converted to Packed Decimal : ^@^FS,^@

Is this conversation possible in java?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but according to the tour you've taken this is neither a good answer nor is "please help me to achieve this" a good question for StackOverflow.
As you now know that it is possible I suggest to give it a try, editing the question with the code you have (which shows not "now convert here" but a try on the conversion) allowing others to help.
I suggest to first check how a comp-3 field is encoded (likely has to do with bytes) and then check how you convert those bytes.

Comment: Would you please edit your question and remove dublicate words, and also show the expected result in a useful way (^@^FS,^@ is not useful)

Answer (score 3):

Similar questions have been answered multiple times already on Stack overflow

For s9(5)V9(4) comp-3, 123.45 is represented in byte format as

```
00 12 34 50 0c
```

The C is the sign

Yes this is possible, the [JRecord package](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jrecord/) will do it (may truncate extra digits though).

The approach is

- to Convert double to a unsigned and unscaled long / BigInteger i.e 123.45 --> 1234500 (for s9(5)v9(4))
- Convert the long to packed decimal

---

At this point there are several approaches

- Repeatably Divide by 100 and use the remainder to lookup the byte value in a an array. See https://github.com/bmTas/JRecord/blob/master/Source/JRecord_Project/JRecord_Common/src/main/java/net/sf/JRecord/Types/smallBin/TypePackedDecimal9.java for an example
- Divide by by 10, use the remainder && shift 4 bit operator to create the answer
- Convert the number to a string, Add the sign char to the end and then **new BigInteger(UnscalledNumberAsString, 16).toByteArray() will do the conversion. See [Conversion](https://github.com/bmTas/JRecord/blob/master/Source/JRecord_Project/JRecord_Common/src/main/java/net/sf/JRecord/Types/TypePackedDecimal.java) for an example